# Android, how to toast my simplexml class?

Tags: android, toast, simple-framework

Sorry, I'm quite new in Android...
I have an activity which creates an object instance of my class:

```
file MyActivity.java:

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Artworks myArtworks;

    ...
    myArtworks = serial.read(Artworks.class, artworksXmlFile);
    ...
}
--------------------------------------------------------------

file Artworks.java:

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;

@Element
public class Artworks {
    @ElementList(entry = "artwork", inline = true)
    private List<Artwork> list;
    ...
}
--------------------------------------------------------------

file Artwork.java:
public class Artwork {
    // how to use here Toast.makeText(..., text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ???
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I use the Toast class (or any UI class) in my class Artwork, which I do never instantiate directly, but it's indirectly created by a call to serial.read(Artworks.class)?
How do I do it, exactly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "static" helper class to maintain a static reference to your Activity's context.  So, before you deserialize your Artwork class, call `UtilClass.setContext(getApplicationContext());`. Then, within your Artwork class, you can retrieve that context and then do something like `Toast.makeText(UtilClass.getContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Artwork {
   Toast.makeText(Artwork.this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Too nice!... But, unfortunately, Toast.makeText(Artwork.this, (CharSequence)"text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() produces: "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Artwork, CharSequence, int)"...